# Text search in PDF files with iPadOS 13

Tags: pdf, search, text, ios

In iOS 12 the Preview builtin in the Files opens a PDF file nicely but there is no text search possibility (magnifier glass). To find a word in a large pdf document it is necessary to reopen the file in Books or other similar app just for the sake of having the magnifier glass built in. How about iOS 13 Preview, is there the text search feature already built in?

Comment: iPadOS/iOS 13 are currently in beta. Do you have a developer/public beta running on any of your devices. The features available in beta may not be final and are liable to change.

Comment: No, I didn't have iPadOS 13 installed, just asking because the way how the text search in pdf files in iOS 12 is very annoying.